# bug in MATLAB when deleting files manually

Tags: matlab

I experience a strange bug in MATLAB R2019b and I wanted to know if this can be reproduced in general (on other releases), or if it is only due to my own incapacity.

If I activate *Pause on Warnings* (*Editor*>*Run*>*Pause on Warnings*)

[image: pause on warnings]

and than delete a file from the *Current Folder*

[image: delete file]

I get paused in the `rmpath` function, throwing the warning

> Warning from `rmpath` (line 71)
>
> ```
>     warning(message('MATLAB:rmpath:DirNotFound', cdirs{ n }( 1:end - 1 )));
> ```

[image: rmpath]

The funny thing is that this does not happen, when I delete the file programmatically

```
delete('Untitled.m')
```

So it must be something with the MATLAB-IDE. Two observations for this:

1. with `delete` I never enter `rmpath`.
2. with `delete`, the file is deleted by the *Editor* still thinks that it exists (No pop-up window when I use *ctrl* + *s* or use *save* in the ribbon) but the *Command Window* correctly complains that it does not exist. If the deletion is done manually (*del*), the *Editor* gets updated (the title switches to `Untitled2*`)

Comment: Does it happen when you have 2 files on that folder? Seems to be trying to delete if from MATLAB path, but maybe it was not on path

Comment: Weird that `rmpath` would be called at all!

Comment: yes, happens with more files in the folder and if I delete a single file or if I delete all files in a folder (or an entire folder) @AnderBiguri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in  MATLAB R2019b and R2020a (and possible a few previous releases). I filed it to the MathWorks, they acknowledged it. I never heard of them again and guess that is was fixed either with R2020b or will be in R2021a.

Nonetheless, a (dirty) workaround is to turn off all "directory not found" warnings in `rmpath`:

```matlab
warning('off','MATLAB:rmpath:DirNotFound');
```